# How does a recursive CTE eliminate duplicates?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, duplicates, sql-server-2014

I'm learning recursive CTEs in the AdventureWorks2012 database using SQL Server 2014 Express.  I think I'm mostly getting the below example (taking from Beginning T-SQL 3rd Edition), but I don't quite understand why the recursive CTE doesn't produce duplicates.

Below is the recursive CTE that I'm trying to understand, it's a standard employee - manager hierarchy.

```
;with orgchart (employeeid, managerid, title, level, node) as (
    --Anchor
    select employeeid
    , managerid
    , title
    , 0
    , convert(varchar(30),'/') 'node'
    from employee
    where managerid is null 
    union all
    --Recursive
    select emp.employeeid
    , emp.managerid
    , emp.title
    , oc.level + 1
    , convert(varchar(30), oc.node + convert(varchar(30),emp.managerid) + '/')
    from employee emp
    inner join orgchart oc on oc.employeeid = emp.managerid 
    )
select employeeid
, managerid
, space(level * 3) + title 'title'
, level
, node
from orgchart
order by node;
```

It works fine, but the question comes when I try to understand what's going on by recreating it via temp tables.  I create a series of temp tables to plug one output into the next query's input and recreate what the recursive CTE does.

```
--Anchor (Level 0)
select employeeid
, managerid
, title
, 0
, convert(varchar(30),'/') 'node'
into #orgchart
from employee
where managerid is null
```

Then I use that temp table to recreate the first level of recursion, at this point it's just the recursive CTE but with temp tables.

```
--Anchor + 1 level
select *
into #orgchart2
from #orgchart
union all
select emp.employeeid
, emp.managerid
, emp.title
, oc.level + 1
, convert(varchar(30), oc.node + convert(varchar(30),emp.managerid) + '/') 
from employee emp
inner join #orgchart oc on oc.employeeid = emp.managerid
```

So far so good, the results make sense.  Then I do it one more time, but here's where it starts to break down:

```
--Anchor + 2 levels
select *
into #orgchart3
from #orgchart2
union all
select emp.employeeid
, emp.managerid
, emp.title
, oc.level + 1
, convert(varchar(30), oc.node + convert(varchar(30),emp.managerid) + '/')
from employee emp
inner join #orgchart2 oc on oc.employeeid = emp.managerid
```

The output from this begins to return duplicate rows (all fields duplicate) of the level 1 employees.  This makes sense - the second query after the UNION ALL will return the previous levels as well as the new level of recursion, and UNION ALL doesn't duplicate.  If I do another round of recursion, the level 2 employees are also duplicated, and so on.

I understand that I can change UNION ALL to UNION in order to remove duplicates, but I'm trying to understand why the recursive CTE doesn't produce duplicates as well?  It uses UNION ALL so I don't understand where the deduplication comes in.  Is removal of duplicates an intrinsic part of a recursive CTE?

I'm trying to post all the result sets, but if they're needed to understand the problem then let me know and I will post them.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't you causing the duplicate yourself with the union in the SQL? if you remove it, you should get just the correct items into the temp. tables and then combine the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that when you populate your #orgchart2, you are including all the rows from #orgchart.   So now when you create #orgchart3 (which represents a 3rd level of recursion), you are joining on the rows from #orgchart as well as #orgchart2.

So when you create the third level in #orgchart3, it is related to rows in both #orgchart and #orgchart2, when it should only be related to #orgchart2.   Instead your third level includes rows that are one level beyond the 2nd level, but also one level beyond the anchor level, so you are duplicating rows, since you already have rows in the second level that are one level beyond the anchor level.

The optimizer knows not to do that with recursive CTEs.   Each level of recursion only looks at the previous one and ignores all the ones that came before it.   So no duplicates are created.

You would simulate what the optimizer does if you left out the top half of the UNION ALL when you populated #orgchart2 and #orgchart3, and then finally produced a single UNION ALL of all three temp tables.

Comment: This is not an explanation, we all know why the op's script generating duplications but the true question is how cte handles this. I mean how exactly, not just something  The optimizer knows not to do that. I have been using cte for years but this keeps coming into my mind.